# Prove this set is open

Tags: general-topology

Let $A \subset X$ be closed and $U \subset A$ open in $A$. Let $V$ be any open
set in $X$ with $U \subset V$.

Prove $U \cup (V \setminus A)$ is open in $X$.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Since $U$ is open in $A$, there is an open set $\mathscr{U}$ of $X$ such that $U = A\cap\mathscr{U}$. Consider the open sets $\mathscr{U}\cap V$ and $V\setminus A$.